# MatchPhrasePrefix on NEST Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I cannot figure out how to search the documents in my index by the MatchPhrasePrefix.  I want to match on the entire search term phrase, but allow prefixes on the last term.

This LINQ construction is giving me back everything with a score of 1.0.  How would I construct this?  On a side note, is there anyway to see the raw query that NEST is constructing?  That would be very helpful!

```
    var search = new SearchDescriptor<ObservationElasticModel>();
        search = search
            .Query(q => q.MatchPhrase(m => m.Query(term)));
     var response = _client.Search<ObservationElasticModel>(search);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **MatchPhrasePrefix** method on the **QueryDescriptor**. You may also need to set the Operator to AND.

```
_client.Search<ObservationElasticModel>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m
            .Operator(Operator.And)
            .Query(term)));
```

You can log raw queries to the debugging console by calling **EnableTrace()** and **ExposeRawResponse()** on the ConnectionSettings instance during setup.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(searchUri));
settings.EnableTrace();
settings.ExposeRawResponse();
_client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```